# how to define and create more of one schedule in a scene cocos?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am  define two schedule in my project but exist a error when building.

Instance Code :

```
this->schedule
    (schedule_selector(GameScreen::spawnAsteroid), 1.0);
```

Comment: Need more details, maybe more code, with that line everything should work. Of course you can override update() function if you need two schedules

Answer (score 0):

instead of this, I think you can use scheduleOnce method of the class Scheduler. Now you can use as many Schedule as per your need.

```
    scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(GameScreen::spawnAsteroid),1.0);
```

For more you can always refer to this link.

[Cocos2d-x official documentation for Scheduler](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.3rc0/dc/d82/classcocos2d_1_1_scheduler.html)

Comment: tnx but i need two schedule forever in my game

Answer (score 0):

Schedule like this:

```
this->schedule(SEL_SCHEDULE(&GameScreen:: spawnAsteroid), 1.0);
```

You can also schedule once:

```
this->scheduleOnce(SEL_SCHEDULE(&GameScreen:: spawnAsteroid), 1.0);
```